# Merge junit-reports after re-running failed tests using Apache Ant

Tags: ant, junit, reporting

I have a test suite which re-runs all the failed tests at the end of the suite execution. But even if the test passes in the second run, junit report displays the output of the first run, ie. it shows that the test failed.

Following is an extract from build.xml:

```
        <junitreport tofile="./report/html/result.xml">
            <fileset dir="./report">
                <include name="result.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report format="noframes" styledir="./etc_time" todir="./report/html/">
            </report>
        </junitreport>
        <copy file="report/html/junit-noframes.html" tofile="report/html/index.html" />
        <fail message="Tests failed" if="test.failed"/>
```

Can someone please point to some tutorials on how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Having tests failed then sucesful without code change is your real problem. Focus on fixing that first.

Comment: Actually it's not a problem with the code. In our framework many test suites are run in parallel. Due to this, sometimes the UI stops responding. If the tests are re-run just after the suite execution finishes, there is 50% chance for the tests to pass. Is there any probable solution for the OP?

Comment: "sometimes the UI stops responding" <- I would call that exactly a problem with the code. Perhaps not _your_ code, but _the_ code nonetheless.

Comment: It might be true. But since I am testing the app and don't have access to the original code, this is the only fix I can think of!